# Datepicker on register form in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, registration, datepicker

I want to add datepicker for selection of date of birth on customer account registration form.

https://prnt.sc/orlaam

I am using the default block  `<?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob')` 
This block works fine on other form, but the same block when used on account registration form it does not work.
What can be the issue?

Comment: Which custom theme you are using?

Comment: @Mitro Smartwave Porto

Comment: Check by swiching to default theme datepicker is working or not. If it works in default theme then it is theme related issue

Comment: @Mitro This is not theme related. as i said its working on account edit form and not on create account form. Basiclly $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() is not working and  <?= $_dob->setDate($block->getCustomer()->getDob())->toHtml() ?> is working

Comment: @Mitro Any help which you can provide